# gcc fails to find a library to link

Tags: c++, gcc, aptana3

I am using Ubuntu and my IDE is Aptana 3.0

I am getting the following error when trying to build.  The library `libfcgi.a` is located in `/usr/local/lib/`.

In the Library C++ Linker section of the project properties, I added `/usr/local/lib/` to the search path and the file `/usr/local/lib/libfcgi.a`.

Why can I still not build?

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project rtb ****

make all 
Building target: rtb
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   -l/usr/local/lib/libfcgi.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libfcgi.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rtb] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you want;

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "rtb" ./src/rtb.o -lfcgi
```

-l<value> will automatically look in all folders listed with -L for a library named lib<value>.a or lib<value>.so, all you need is the '-lfcgi'.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `/usr/local/lib` wasn't already in the search path for libraries

Comment: On my mac it's not, better safe than sorry :)

Comment: It is likely that it's not. It it also likely it is not in ld.conf or LD_LIBRARY_PATH...

Answer (score 0):

Try "-lfcgi" instead

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   -lfcgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linker flag is wrong it needs to be `-lfcgi` and not the whole path with the "lib" prefix and the .a suffix.

You can change it by hand, or in Apatana. To do so you don't have to give him the full qualified path to your lib two times. ( You already gave him the search path, remember? ). Usually you define additional libraries just like this:
`cfgi` and your IDE does the rest to add it to the linker flags!

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
g++ -o "rtb" ./src/rtb.o -lfcgi
```

In the unlikely case that `/usr/local/lib/` is *not* in your search path, you can either add that path in the command line like

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "rtb" ./src/rtb.o -lfcgi
```

or put it in the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` before calling your compile command, e.g. with bash:

```sh
if [ -z "$LIBRARY_PATH" ];
  then export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib;
  else export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH":/usr/local/lib;
fi
```

If you insist in giving the explicit file name, omit the `-l`:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   /usr/local/lib/libfcgi.a
```

However I'd advise against that because it's inflexible. If the issue is that there's another, incompatible version of the library installed, it's better to make sure that the correct one comes first in the search path (or even better, make sure that the wrong one isn't in the search path at all ― maybe even by removing it from the system).

Answer (score 0):

That's for the help all....really appreciate it.

Here is the solution.  I had to use -lfcgi++ and I added the

g++ -L/usr/local/include/ -lfcgi++ -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o

The above was the output from aptanta console.  I tried -lfcgi and did not work.  Google search lead to using -lfcgi++.